# discord.py : bot.wait_for() intercept message.add_reaction() and work one time

Tags: python, discord

I have a problem with discord.py.

I want to do something like this:

```py
msg = await ctx.author.send('message')
await msg.add_reaction('✅')
await msg.add_reaction('❎')

def check(reaction, user):
    return user != bot.user and reaction.message.id == choice.id and reaction.emoji in ['✅', '❎']

r, u = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
result = r.emoji == '✅'
```

But it doesn't work and when I try this:

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    print(user.name)
    return user != bot.user and reaction.message.id == choice.id and reaction.emoji in ['✅', '❎']
```

I have the name of the bot in the console, and when I try to click on a reaction nothing is printed, so I think `bot.wait_for()` works one time?

I hope you'll understand. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your check, you had `reaction.message.id == choice.id`, and I'm not sure what `choice` is. This should work:

```
message = await ctx.author.send("message")
await message.add_reaction("✅")
await message.add_reaction("❎")

def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and reaction.message == message and reaction.emoji in ["✅", "❎"]

response = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
result = response[0].emoji == "✅"
```